# JSON to display image based on 100% completion

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calculated-column, json-formatting

I have a list where we track an employees performance by awarding badges. When 4 badges are earned, the employee achieves a Pennant. I have a calculated column for Progress that adjusts by 25% with each badge earned, and is also formatted to displays color coded bars.

Calculated Progress field JSON:

```
=IF(Achievement4>0,"1.00",IF(Achievement3>0,".75",IF(Achievement2>0,".50",IF(Achievement1>0,".25",))))
```

I can't get the Pennant image to display.  I don't get an error with my JSON, but the field is blank. I want the Pennant column to display the pennant image when the Progress reaches 100%.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "img",
  "style": {
    "width": "100px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "src": "=if([$Progress]='1.00', 'https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/HR/SiteAssets/Servicers.png', ''))"

  }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and/or why my Pennant isn't displaying when the Progress field reaches 100%?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use calculated column formula and settings like this:

```
=IF([Achievement4]>0,1,IF([Achievement3]>0,0.75,IF([Achievement2]>0,0.50,IF([Achievement1]>0,0.25,""))))
```

[image]

Then use JSON column formatting like below to show the image when progress is 100%:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "img",
  "style": {
    "width": "100px",
    "display": "=if([$Progress]==1, 'block', 'none')"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "src": "=if([$Progress]==1, 'https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/HR/SiteAssets/Servicers.png', '')"
  }
}
```

Where `Progress` is the internal name of your SharePoint list calculated column. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Example Output**:

[image]

Comment: That worked!!  Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked for you!

Comment: I am checking the status of this case. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.
If you have any update about this issue, please feel free to post back.

Comment: Hi @user110812, can you please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) & [accept my response as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future. It also removes this question from "Unanswered Questions" list. Thank you!